# Jquery plugin editable with values from PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the jquery editable plugin http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable.

I need my drop down selection to be populated from the database.

So I have something like this :

```
$(".edit_company").editable("banner-save.php", { 
indicator : '<img src="img/indicator.gif">',
data   : "{ 'Package 1' : 'Package 1', 'Package 2' : 'Package 2'  }",
type   : "select",
submit : "OK",
event     : "dblclick",
submitdata : function() {
  return {type : 'package'};
}
```

});

The 'data' there, I need to populate it from an array, something like

```
$query=mysql_query("select * from company"); 
while ($query as $comp) { 
  // how 
}
```

How can I pass the values I get from the query into the 'data' in the js?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accumulate your query rows into a PHP associative array and `json_encode()` it into the jQuery plugin.

```
$data = array();
// Assuming you had a column called `name` in your query...
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  $data[$row['name']] = $row['name'];
}
```

This produces an array something like the following.  Supply the correct column names from your query to get the `key : value` pairs you need.

```
Array
(
    [Name 1] => Name 1
    [Name 2] => Name 2
    [Name 3] => Name 3
)
```

.. which produces the JSON:

```
{"Name 1":"Name 1","Name 2":"Name 2","Name 3":"Name 3"}
```

Pass it into the jQuery plugin via `json_encode()`.

```
$(".edit_company").editable("banner-save.php", { 
  indicator : '<img src="img/indicator.gif">',
  // json_encode() will supply the correct format.
  data   : '<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>',
  type   : "select",
  ...
});
```

It is weird that the JSON is passed as a string rather than a plain object into the JavaScript, but this is consistent with examples [in the documentation for the plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable).

Based on the documentation, if there is a specific option you would like selected by default, you can set that in the PHP array like:

```
// Start with Name 3 selected
$data['selected'] = 'Name 3';
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your reply. Your method makes sense, however when I apply onto my script, data   : '<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>' is not working. 
I might use another turnaround, perhaps not using the editable plugin.

I will wait if there's other suggestions, if not I will accept your answer as it does help me to understand. :)

Comment: @Sylph What isn't working? Did you populate your array? Does the JSON output PHP produces look like you expect it to?

Comment: Hi Michael, Sorry I didn't check back the post. The JSON did output it correctly, but funny thing is when put it in the javascript, it doesn't read it.